# Deal with (long-term) connection drops in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timeout, node-mongodb-native

I'm writing a web application that uses stores. If the client doesn't receive a response within 30 seconds, it considers the request dead and gives a timeout error.

I'm trying to get **MongoDB** to do the same thing. If for example the connection drops for 1 minute, the driver will attempt to re-connect and will leave the client's request hanging till the reconnection is successful. So, things like `socketTimeoutMS` (which I managed to get to work) are not effective here.

What's the best way to get **MongoDB** to "give up" on a request after N seconds?

The last thing I want is give the client a timeout error -- with the server actually completing the requests 5 minutes later!

Answer (score 1):

There is [`maxTimeMS`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_4_and_2_6.html#maxtimems) option introduced in 2.6:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
    // Get an aggregation cursor
    var cursor = db.collection('data')
        .find("$where": "sleep(1000) || true")
        .maxTimeMS(50);

    // Get alll the items
    cursor.toArray(function(err, items) {
        console.dir(err);
        console.dir(items);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: But that means that I would have to apply it for every query, right? Plus, "Network latency and idle time for a cursor do not count toward MaxTimeMS." -- and network latency is what I am after... http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73939/mongodb-maxtimems-ignored

Comment: Any idea on how to use MaxTimeMS with findOne function?